# tabs using css html in phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am making tabs using css and html for mobile devices. My current code show some weird behavior. My current code shows the tabs which is shown in image below. You ca see that tabs are all misplaced and the icon inside these tabs are slightly on the right side but I want this to be in the center of the tab. I can move that icons towards left to make it appear in the center in photoshop but again if I test this app on larger screen mobile devices then this icon will appear on the left side. I want them to be always in the center. So please tell me how can I make this more better tabs as normal mobile apps have?

here is mu html code

```
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li class="tabs"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="tabs"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="tabs"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

here is my css

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #535353; 
}
footer ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0; 
}
footer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31%;
  height: 50px; 
}
footer ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  background: url(../../../img/tabs.png) top left no-repeat; 
}
```

here is the image:

[image]

**Update**

Here is my new css

```
footer {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
padding: 0;
background: #ccc; }
footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center; }
  footer ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden; }
    footer ul li a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 1px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: url(../../../img/tabs.png) center no-repeat;
      /*
      &.home {
        background: url(../../../img/tabs.png) top left no-repeat;
      }
      &.profile {
        background: url(../../../img/tabs.png) top left no-repeat;
      }
      &.cam {
        background: url(../../../img/tabs.png) top left no-repeat;
      }*/ }
      footer ul li a.current {
        margin-top: 5%;
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
        background-color: #ccc;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #666;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #666;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #666; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymKkK/1/). What I did

- `text-align: center` to the `ul`, so this is inherited and everything is centered
- `line-height` set the same as `width`, so everything is vertically centered
- list elements are `display:block`, `width: 33.33%` and `float:left` - Also I added `overflow:hidden`
- `a` elements have `width: 100%` and `margin: 1px`

You can now play with it, by adding images and/or real text.

Comment: Hi but when I want to add images it does not show up. Images are in the correct directory.

Comment: Images are only visible when I add some text inside anchor tags. Here is how I am adding  images. `background: url(../../../img/tabs.png) top left no-repeat;`

Comment: But I do not want the text. I only want icons.

Comment: Could see my updated css? It still does not work for me. If i add any text to links then its fine otherwise it does not show background images at all.

Comment: You could try to insert a space `" "`, or you'd better throwing the background image away and using a plain `<img>` element. See [update 3](http://jsfiddle.net/ymKkK/3/)